# A listener TCP/IP socket in a windows service

Tags: vb.net, service, tcp

I want to create a windows service to run a listener TCP/IP socket. The listener TCP/IP socket has a 'While True' loop and works in a windows application. I have a simple windows service with a timer and it works, but when I include the TCP/IP socket in the windows service it does not work. I get an error message: 'The XXX service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs." Does anybody have a clue about this?

This is the basic code to start the TCP/IP listener:

```
    Dim bytes() As Byte = New [Byte](1024) {}

    localEndPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(IPA, C_PORT)
    listener = New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, _
        System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)
    listener.Bind(localEndPoint)
    listener.Listen(10)
    While True
        Dim handler As System.Net.Sockets.Socket = listener.Accept()
        data = Nothing
        While True
            bytes = New Byte(1024) {}
            Dim bytesRec As Integer = handler.Receive(bytes)
            data += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec)
            If data.IndexOf(Chr(28) & Chr(13)) > -1 Then
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
        s = data
        Dim m As M2_GIS.Tools.HL7.C_Message
        m = New M2_GIS.Tools.C_Message
        m.MessageString = s
        m.P_Read()
        m.P_GetMessageData()
        Dim Response As String
        Response = m.F_ReceivedAcknowledgement
        A2_p1.Value = s
        A2_p12.Value = Response
        m.DaedalusPK = CInt(A2_Cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        m.P_UpdateDatabase()
        Dim msg As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Response)
        handler.Send(msg)
        handler.Shutdown(System.Net.Sockets.SocketShutdown.Both)
        handler.Close()
    End While
```

listener and localEndPoint are properties of the class.
The M2_GIS.Tools.HL7.C_Message class is just my own class to handle the incoming message.The A2_ variables are to run a SQL Server stored procedure to save the message in a database.

Comment: Please include a minimal "working" example to reproduce the issue in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your service thread ended because monitoring is probably not set correctly.

```
Dim listener As New TcpListener(8000)

listener.Start()

While(True)

// Wait for data from client, do some stuff

End While

listener.Stop()
```

That should keep your service running.

Comment: The code that I have (see below) run perfectly OK as

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The code that I have runs perfectly OK as a windows application, but it does not work in a windows service. So there is nothing wrong with the code itself, unless there are things that are incompatible with a windows service, that I don't know.

The listener I am using does not have a start method.
listener = New System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp)

I use the bind and listen methods.

Thank you again.